# React-Native MapBox Clustering with custom icons

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

How to perform clustering in React Native Mapbox with custom icons.

i have checked the earthquake clustering example given on GitHub page of mapbox react native. but i need something different like, i need to do clustering with custom icons. i have 2 types of data/points on map one is user and other is events both have different icons so i need to render those custom icons in clustering.

also on tap of that icon i need to show a pulse animation behind that icon. any possible way to do this?

here is my code for implementing mapbox :-

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
                            ref={(ref) => this.map = ref}
                            showUserLocation={store.homeStore.locationAlowed}
                            zoomLevel={11}
                            pitch={45}
                            centerCoordinate={[store.userStore.longitude, store.userStore.latitude]}
                            userTrackingMode={MapboxGL.UserTrackingModes.follow}
                            styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Street}
                            style={{
                                position: store.homeStore.mapPosition,
                                top: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                bottom: 0,
                            }}
                            logoEnabled={false}
                            compassEnabled={false}
                            attributionEnabled={false}
                            onDidFinishRenderingMapFully={() => this.map.takeSnap(true).then((resp) => {
                                if (resp) {
                                    store.homeStore.mapImageSource = resp;
                                }
                            })}
                            onPress={this.onMapPress.bind(this)}>
                            {store.homeStore.setLocationOnMap && store.homeStore.eventData.length > 0 ?
                                store.homeStore.eventData.map((prop, key) => {
                                    return (
                                        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                                            key={prop.id}
                                            id={prop.id}
                                            coordinate={[parseFloat(prop.evt_longitude), parseFloat(prop.evt_latitude)]} >
                                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectEventOnMap.bind(this, prop)} style={{ height: vh * 0.109 }}>
                                                <View style={styles.likesContainer}>
                                                    <Image source={require('../Images/ic_home_event_likes.png')}
                                                        style={[styles.heartImage, prop.event_likes > 999 ? { marginLeft: vw * 0.018 } :
                                                            prop.event_likes > 9 ? { marginLeft: vw * 0.036 } : { marginLeft: vw * 0.049 }]} />
                                                    <Text style={[styles.likesText, prop.event_likes < 10 ? { marginLeft: 2 } : '']}>
                                                        {prop.event_likes > 999 ? (Math.round(prop.event_likes / 1000) + " k") : prop.event_likes}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <Image source={require('../Images/ic_home_inactive_event_pin.png')}
                                                    style={{
                                                        height: vh * 0.098, width: vw * 0.15, marginTop: vh * 0.017,
                                                        tintColor: (prop.userid == store.userStore.id ? Colors.Blue : Colors.warmPink)
                                                    }} />
                                                <Image source={this.getImageSource(prop.evt_category)}
                                                    style={{
                                                        height: vh * 0.041, width: vw * 0.077,
                                                        top: vh * 0.035, left: vw * 0.038, position: 'absolute'
                                                    }} />
                                                {prop.selected && <Pulse style={{ zIndex: -1, position: 'absolute', top: -((vh * 0.109) / 3) }}
                                                    color={Colors.warmPink} numPulses={6} diameter={100} speed={18} duration={1000} />}
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
                                    );
                                }) : null}
                            {store.homeStore.setLocationOnMap && store.homeStore.peopleData.length > 0 ?
                                store.homeStore.peopleData.map((prop, key) => {
                                    return (
                                        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                                            key={prop.userid}
                                            id={prop.userid}
                                            coordinate={[parseFloat(prop.longitude), parseFloat(prop.latitude)]} >
                                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { store.homeStore.showProfileCard = true; store.homeStore.userData = prop; }}>
                                                <View style={{
                                                    height: vw * 0.130, width: vw * 0.130, borderRadius: (vw * 0.130) / 2,
                                                    backgroundColor: Colors.Blue, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'
                                                }}>
                                                    <AsyncImage source={{ uri: prop.image }}
                                                        style={{
                                                            height: vw * 0.122, width: vw * 0.122, borderRadius: (vw * 0.122) / 2
                                                        }} placeholderColor='#b3e5fc' />
                                                </View>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
                                    );
                                }) : null}
                            {this.renderRoute()}
                            {/* <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
                                id='earthquakes'
                                cluster
                                clusterRadius={50}
                                clusterMaxZoom={14}
                                url='http://moso.appinventive.com/public/accesscsv/data.json'>
                                <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
                                    id='pointCount'
                                    style={layerStyles.clusterCount} />
                                <MapboxGL.CircleLayer
                                    id='singlePoint'
                                    filter={['!has', 'point_count']}
                                    style={layerStyles.singlePoint} />
                            </MapboxGL.ShapeSource> */}
                            {/* <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
                                id='talesMarkers'
                                shape={jsonData}
                                cluster
                                clusterRadius={50}
                                clusterMaxZoom={14}
                            >
                                <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer key='{id}' id='{id}' style={styles.icon} />
                            </MapboxGL.ShapeSource> */}
                        </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

and here is the json data :-

```
const jsonData = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "27",
                "evt_name": "nh24 event",
                "evt_latitude": "28.624134137261",
                "evt_longitude": "77.399671500871",
                "evt_start": "1520855452",
                "evt_category": "1",
                "event_address": "Pusta Road, Bahrampur, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 203207, India",
                "evt_createdon": "1520855452",
                "userid": "23",
                "image": "https://appinventiv-development.s3.amazonaws.com/moso%2FnCA3HzIs7OsAVLYVJ6Db",
                "event_likes": "0",
                "event_followers": "0",
                "distance": "2.6069925023499723",
                "view": false,
                "event_growth": 0,
                "owner_popularity": 0,
                "viral": 0,
                "icon": 'airport-15'
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    77.399671500871,
                    28.624134137261,
                    6.55
                ]
            },
            "id": "27"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "26",
                "evt_name": "event with exact address",
                "evt_latitude": "28.611121352303",
                "evt_longitude": "77.385811577333",
                "evt_start": "1520839916",
                "evt_category": "1",
                "event_address": "Sector 65, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India",
                "evt_createdon": "1520839916",
                "userid": "23",
                "image": "https://appinventiv-development.s3.amazonaws.com/moso%2FnCA3HzIs7OsAVLYVJ6Db",
                "event_likes": "0",
                "event_followers": "0",
                "distance": "1.489932977056515",
                "view": false,
                "event_growth": 0,
                "owner_popularity": 0,
                "viral": 0,
                "icon": 'airport-15'
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    77.385811577333,
                    28.611121352303,
                    1.67
                ]
            },
            "id": "26"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "userid": "13",
                "name": "",
                "username": "howdy",
                "latitude": 28.577006492753625,
                "longitude": 77.32924537095796,
                "facebookprof": "",
                "instaprof": "",
                "image": "https://appinventiv-development.s3.amazonaws.com/moso%2FchMzFARwXj2z1y3MYASk",
                "createdon": "1519757532",
                "user_bio": "",
                "user_likes": "1",
                "user_followers": "1",
                "distance": "0.021139920338468652",
                "liked": false,
                "follows": false,
                "view": false,
                "live_events": "0",
                "user_growth": 1.3149888133309905e-9,
                "user_popularity": 0.00046882325363338024,
                "viral": 1.1720601065666707e-8,
                "icon": 'airport-15'
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    77.32924537095796,
                    28.577006492753625,
                    77.7
                ]
            },
            "id": "13"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "userid": "20",
                "name": null,
                "username": "otheruser",
                "latitude": 28.606038365831,
                "longitude": 77.362243836846,
                "facebookprof": "",
                "instaprof": "",
                "image": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c59.0.200.200/p200x200/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=f621f9474a63f5b27b0514adda5db42b&oe=5B0F8625",
                "createdon": "1519776475",
                "user_bio": "",
                "user_likes": "1",
                "user_followers": "1",
                "distance": "0.019360181909683884",
                "liked": false,
                "follows": false,
                "view": false,
                "live_events": "0",
                "user_growth": 1.3149888133309905e-9,
                "user_popularity": 0.0000017414245723714283,
                "viral": 4.35553391414857e-11,
                "icon": 'airport-15'
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    77.362243836846,
                    28.606038365831,
                    1.6
                ]
            },
            "id": "20"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "userid": "23",
                "name": "vijay",
                "username": "vijaysharma",
                "latitude": 28.577006492753625,
                "longitude": 77.32924537095796,
                "facebookprof": "https://www.gmail.com",
                "instaprof": "https://www.gmail.com",
                "image": "https://appinventiv-development.s3.amazonaws.com/moso%2FnCA3HzIs7OsAVLYVJ6Db",
                "createdon": "1520588433",
                "user_bio": "Usheiwhwosbwowgwiwgwowwjai9a7292ue8rgdidbdidhndjdjdjdjsksoa9wub3829283yehs8dyv3i38sieh3i39w83hejwuhe",
                "user_likes": "0",
                "user_followers": "0",
                "distance": "0.021139920338468652",
                "liked": false,
                "follows": false,
                "view": false,
                "live_events": "0",
                "user_growth": 0,
                "user_popularity": 0,
                "viral": 0,
                "icon": 'airport-15'
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    77.32924537095796,
                    28.577006492753625,
                    44.5
                ]
            },
            "id": "23"
        }
    ]
}
```

with pointAnnotations i am able to show points on map but this way clustering is not performed on mapbox. and if i try to make points on map from clustering using shapesource layer and json data then i am not getting how to use my custom icons. also i need to fire a click event on tap of that custom pin and show pulse loading animation behind that point.

please take a look at screenshots also what i need to do with clustering. 
screenshots shown only point annotations with which clustering is not happening.

[mapbox point annotations without clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUE1x.png)

Comment: Can you add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to your question showing what you tried so far and where exactly you have issues?

Comment: @NOhs please check post now. i have updated my post with code and images.  i want to perform clustering on mapbox react native with my custom icons.

Comment: @VijaySharma Have you found the solution for this? For me i can show custom icon as symbol source, and its working with iOS (But its showing only one time, if i go to next page and navigate to this page clusters are NOT showing) And its not showing even one time with Android